# Convert function to string saving original formatting

Tags: r

When I create function in R, the function remembers the formatting used to create it, including the whitespace. This can be revealed by printing the function:

```
> f <- function( x )   {if  (x==1) {x} else {x+1}}
> print(f)
function( x )   {if  (x==1) {x} else {x+1}}
```

How do I extract that representation from the function; for example, to save it to a variable for further manipulation?

Comment: `repr <- capture.output(f)` ?

Comment: Hi, you can use `paste0(deparse(body(f)), collapse="")`

Comment: @Matthew I thought about that, but that's not quite ideal.

Comment: @Mamoun That does not preserve the formatting.

Comment: Right, the formatting is lost when you transform it to character. I thought about using **collapse = "\n"**, but it does not work :(.